# js code to remove space between numbers in a string

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to remove the spaces just numbers in a string?

```
var str = "The store is 5 6 7 8"
```

after processing the output should be like this:

```
"The store is 5678"
```

How to do this?

Comment: so what you have tried so far.. and will this be the same string as static

Comment: var str = 'the store is 1 2 3 4'

console.log(str.replace(/ /g,''));

console.log(str);

This code replaces all spaces in the string...  But i want only the spaces between the number to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can try this.

```
var str = "The store is 5 6 7 8"
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
str.split(/[0-9]+/).join("") + str.match(regex).join('')
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: This places the digits at the end of the string even when they're in the middle in the original one. Gabriel's answer below does the job right

Answer (score 9):

This is very close to santosh singh answer, but will not replace the space between `is` and `5`.

```js
const regex = /(\d)\s+(?=\d)/g;
const str = `The store is 5 6 7 8`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

https://regex101.com/r/nSZfQR/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code snippet.

```
const regex = /(?!\d) +(?=\d)/g;
const str = `The store is 5 6 7 8`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/` - removes space between digits.
But running s.replace replaces only first occurrences.
I put in into loop, so it keep deleting all spaces between two digits until there is no more spaces between digits.

```
prevS = ''; 
while(prevS !== s){
   prevS = s; s = s.replace(/([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/, '$1$2');
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, it could do with a little bit of explanation about why and how it answers the question otherwise it is likely to get deleted - From Review